# How to append parent object from an external file including all the children?

Tags: append, parent

I would like to append a very complicated hierarchy tree from another file. The file has multi-level parent-children relations and I'd like to append the whole structure just by appending it's main parent object. The hierarchy should be maintained after appending.

I don't want to manually select among the hundreds of objects those belonging to the hierarchy tree and I don't want to use Groups. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use groups?

Comment: Solution with groups requires messing with source files and I'd like to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked around and a user JA12 on #blender irc channel suggested me the following:

1. **Open up the source scene**, select the parent object in the Outliner with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*Left Click*, that will select all levels of children as well
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Copy) while those objects are selected, that will copy the selection to the buffer
3. Close the **source scene** and open up the **destination scene**
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Paste)

**Note:** *Copy Attributes Add-on* prevents default copy action.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. Get an error `No buffer to paste from`.

Comment: It definitely does work, I tried it in 2.75 and 2.73. Please check if you have "Copy Attributes" addon enabled, that prevents default CTRL+C action to be executed and remaps it to addon-specific menu. If yes, disable it. All addons that remap CTRL+C or CTRL+V shortcut to different action will cause this solution to fail.

Comment: Yes "Copy Attributes" enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use groups:

1. Open the source .blend file.
2. Select the entire hierarchy (see step 1 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33300/29270).
3. Create a new group.
4. Add the selection to the new group.
5. Now save the source .blend file.
6. Open the destination .blend file.
7. Now append the newly created group from the source .blend file.

Comment: I specifically said in the original question that I don't want to use groups.